# Defrag Terms Description

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ntfs, defragment

There are 3 terms used in the `Windows defrager`. **Relocated**, **consolidated** and **defragmented**. Can someone give me some clarification *of them*?

Comment: Please [edit] and give the source where you saw these terms and which defrag program you are referring to.

Comment: @DavidPostill it can be seen during defragmentation with command `defrag /c /u`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only explanation I have found is the following. It seems a reasonable explanation.

> The sequence is Relocated, Defragmented and Consolidated.
>
> Relocated likely refers to gathering the chunks of non-contiguous
>   blocks into some semblance of order from wherever they are on the
>   disk.
>
> Defragmented likely means that each chunk then gets defragmented into
>   something that more closely resembles the files they are a part of.
>
> Consolidated likely means that each piece of the files is pulled from
>   wherever the previous relocation and defragmentation put them into
>   chunks of similar files.
>
> That is one pass.
>
> But since the defragmenter did not move all your files so that the
>   more consolidated chunks (or file) can neatly sit within one
>   contiguous piece of disk acreage, probably for performance reasons -
>   if the defragger did it every time you defragged your drive it might
>   mean that some measly 1MB chunk has to be opened up on the disk for a
>   file near the beginning of the disk which means, perhaps a huge chunk
>   of other contiguous files have to be move. And don't forget that you
>   might have a number of files that have to be treated that way.
>
> So, after pass 1, you have scattered about your drive, relatively
>   contiguous chunks of files. Hence pass 2 to assemble the scattered
>   pieces together in whatever order they get picked up, then defragged,
>   then consolidated again.
>
> So on. I have seen my disk defragmenter go up to 8 passes though the
>   last few may zoom past.
>
> So I suppose that the multiple passes is an attempt to get reasonable
>   performance out of an action that is supposed to be low priority
>   compared to one's actively using the computer.

Source [There are 3 terms used in the defrager..relocated,consolidated and defragmented. Can someone give me some clarification of them?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/there-are-3-terms-used-in-the/2acef503-5f5a-4a5d-9547-4a6d5a244bda)